# How do you make bows set things on fire?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

Can someone tell me how to make bows set things on fire? I tried enchanting, but it doesn't make them set things on fire.

Comment: From what I understand enchanting is how you do that.
Are you sure you enchanting correctly?

Comment: yep, I am... i figured out the problem now. Thanks.

Comment: Just in case you're unaware: A flaming arrow (you can also make an arrow a flaming arrow by firing it through lava flow) will not set anything on fire except creatures.

Comment: Are you sure? I would swear I remember seeing my flame-bow set grass on fire.

Comment: Do you mean by shooting arrows or hittng with the actual bow.

Answer (score 23):

You need a specific bow enchantment to set things on fire: [The Flame enchantment](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Enchanting#Bow_Enchantments).

The [enchantment](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Enchanting) you get on an item is going to be [randomly chosen](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Enchanting#How_Enchantments_Are_Chosen), so you'll just have to keep trying until you get a bow that has one. It should be noted that the probability of getting the Flame enchantment on a bow is fairly low, and if the modified enchantment level is less than 19 it is *impossible* to get.

If you are in creative, you can look up the enchanted book with the Flame enchantment, and with a normal bow, combine them in an anvil, and you get the flaming bow...

Comment: Thanks guys, I thought my minecraft game wasn't working or something, so that's good to hear. :D

Comment: @HusseinHorack, you should consider accepting an answer if it solved your doubt =)

Comment: @HusseinHorack click in the gray check mark if this answers the question. The arrow should be green.

Answer (score 1):

To set arrows on fire you can shoot them through running lava or use an enchantment.

Comment: While the mentioned methods do set the arrow on fire, they do not set the entity that the arrow lands on on fire.

Comment: @kuyan Um, actually they both do...

Comment: @Timtech - This may have changed since the posting of my comment on November 12, 2012. I haven't played Minecraft in a while, so I don't know - I'll take your word for it. :)

Comment: @kuyan ok, great

Comment: @kuyan they do go on fire! I tried it myself on the latest patch and the mobs were burning!