# How do I make a fire bow?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do you make bows set things on fire?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/65121/how-do-you-make-bows-set-things-on-fire)

In minecraft, how do I make a fire bow that shoots fire arrows? When you shoot it at something like a skeleton, the skeleton would set on fire in the way when it is shot through lava.

Comment: hint: [enchanting](http://www.minecraftwiki.net/wiki/Enchanting)

Comment: There is a feature called the search bar, it's your best friend.

Answer (score 4):

To make a flame bow you need to [enchant](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Enchanting) a bow using an [enchantment table](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Enchantment_Table).

Based of calculations using the [Minecraft enchantment simulator](http://cloud.github.com/downloads/Zazcallabah/mce/mce.v1.9.html) you nee to be enchanting using at least 5 levels in order to have any chance of getting the flame enchantment. Best results can be found by enchanting at the maximum level(30).

Comment: You can also shoot arrows through lava to set them on fire.